# KSQL connection issues with kafka

Tags: ksqldb

Provide details of the setup you're running
Let us know what version of KSQL you're running, what OS, etc,
KSQL version: confluent-ksql-5.3.1-1.
Outline your question
Ask you question!
KSQL not able to connect to the kafka, resulting in timeout expception.

Following is the ksql configuration file:

```
bootstrap.servers=hostname1:9093
listeners=http://0.0.0.0:8088
ksql.logging.processing.topic.auto.create=true
ksql.logging.processing.stream.auto.create=true
#ksql.schema.registry.url=?
ksql.security.protocol=ssl
ksql.ssl.keystore.location=/root/.kafka/kafka.server.keystore.jks
ksql.ssl.keystore.password=password
ksql.ssl.key.password=password
ksql.ssl.client.auth=true
ksql.streams.state.dir=/etc/ksql/
ksql.ssl.truststore.location=/root/.kafka/kafka.server.truststore.jks
ksql.ssl.truststore.password=password

ERROR:
[

    2019-11-12 14:17:27,790] ERROR Failed to start KSQL (io.confluent.ksql.rest.server.KsqlServerMain:62)
    io.confluent.ksql.util.KsqlServerException: Could not get Kafka cluster configuration!
    at io.confluent.ksql.services.KafkaClusterUtil.getConfig(KafkaClusterUtil.java:77)
    at io.confluent.ksql.engine.TopicAccessValidatorFactory.isKafkaAuthorizerEnabled(TopicAccessValidatorFactory.java:66)
    at io.confluent.ksql.engine.TopicAccessValidatorFactory.create(TopicAccessValidatorFactory.java:50)
    at io.confluent.ksql.rest.server.KsqlRestApplication.buildApplication(KsqlRestApplication.java:505)
    at io.confluent.ksql.rest.server.KsqlRestApplication.buildApplication(KsqlRestApplication.java:444)
    at io.confluent.ksql.rest.server.KsqlServerMain.createExecutable(KsqlServerMain.java:94)
    at io.confluent.ksql.rest.server.KsqlServerMain.main(KsqlServerMain.java:59)
    Caused by: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.apache.kafka.common.errors.TimeoutException: Timed out waiting for a node assignment.
    at org.apache.kafka.common.internals.KafkaFutureImpl.wrapAndThrow(KafkaFutureImpl.java:45)
    at org.apache.kafka.common.internals.KafkaFutureImpl.access$000(KafkaFutureImpl.java:32)
    at org.apache.kafka.common.internals.KafkaFutureImpl$SingleWaiter.await(KafkaFutureImpl.java:89)
    at org.apache.kafka.common.internals.KafkaFutureImpl.get(KafkaFutureImpl.java:260)
    at io.confluent.ksql.services.KafkaClusterUtil.getConfig(KafkaClusterUtil.java:55)
    ... 6 more
    Caused by: org.apache.kafka.common.errors.TimeoutException: Timed out waiting for a node assignment.
```

Comment: ksql.security.protocol=ssl changed to security.protocol=ssl, WORKED

Answer (score 0):

Your config `bootstrap.servers=hostname1:9093` is wrong! You must declare exactly your Kafka bootstrap server like: `192.168.2.1:9092` or `your_host_name:your_Kafka_port`!

Answer (score 0):

bootstrap.servers should be the Kafka bootstrap server host ip / url and port.

example

`bootstrap.servers=localhost:9092`  # if kafka is running on the same machine